# LoopBack and MongoDb, embadsMany relation returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to set up the following 2 models to be related:
I have Labels and records, each label has many records in it.

Here are my model definitions:

***labels.json***

```
 {
  "name": "label",
  "plural": "labels",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "records": {
      "type": "array",
      "required": true
    },
    ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "records": {
      "type": "embedsMany",
      "model": "Record",
      "options": {
        "forceId": false,
        "validate": true,
        "persistent": false
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

***records.json***

```
{
  "name": "Record",
  "plural": "records",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id":{
      "type": "string",
      "defaultFn":"uuid",
      "id":true
     }
  ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

When I try to get `/api/labels?filter={"include":"records"}`, I am expecting (and according to my swagger description) an array of objects, where for the property "records" I get an array of objects, whee each object is a record, but I get an empty array for "records, like so

```
[
  {
    "success": false,
    "id": "5dd19674d16d73109cdd0ab9",
    "_records": [],
    "records": [
      "5dd19674d16d73109cdd0ab8"
    ]
  },
 ...
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your code.

Comment: I shared all my code. Is there anything else needed for configuration here? (Note: I am using loopback)

Comment: BTW - "_records" is an empty array, but "records" is an array with a single element.

Comment: I know, this i probably coming from the DB, I wonder why the relation does not work, and it does not get populated with the actual record as an array of objects.

Comment: Did you create a controller?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the comment "i get an empty array, like so" but then you show an array that is not empty.  I am confused.

Comment: I meant to say, that _records is an empty array, I will edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204080/discussion-between-shimon-brandsdorfer-and-barrypicker).